# Insert text at specific line python

Tags: python

I am using the following code to insert  text on a line:

```
exp = 82
with open ('test.txt','r') as b:
    lines = b.readlines()
with open('test.txt','w') as b:
    for i,line in enumarate(lines):
        if i == exp:
            f.write('test_data')
        f.write(line)
```

This inserts the text at line 82. How can modify it so that it can insert text at line 82 when it runs for the first time then line 83 the next time it runs, then line 84 etc. I was thinking of using a counter but I am unsure.

Comment: Please  [edit] your question and fix the quoting. As you can see from the syntax highlighting done by SO, your question does not contain valid Python code.

Comment: What do you mean next time? Is that in the same process? Or does it have to remember between runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a text file to store how many times the code has run already. Read this value from the text file and add it to the ex. Then increment the value of number of times the code has run and write it to your textfile and then run the code you have written.

```
counterFile = open("counter.txt","r") #counter.txt stores the number of times code has been run. Just create this file manually
counter = counterFile.read()
if(len(counter) == 0):
    counter = 0
else:
    counter = int(counter)
counterFile.close()

exp = 0
with open ('test.txt','r') as b:
    lines = b.readlines()
with open('test.txt','w') as b:
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        print i
        if i == exp+counter:
            b.write('test_data\n')
        b.write(line)

counter += 1
counterFile = open("counter.txt","w")
counterFile.write(str(counter))
counterFile.close()
```

Comment: This works well. Especially when the script is run on different days.

Answer (score 1):

the way to do this would be to increment a counter.

```
counter = exp
stop = 90
with open('test.txt', 'w') as b:
     for i, line in enumerate(lines):
           if i == counter and i != stop:
               b.write('test_data')
               b.write(line)
           else:
                break
           counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to completely loop through the file you can use the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

exp = 5
seq = ["This is new line\n","This is new line\n"]
# Open a file
fo = open("foo.txt", "r+b")

lngth = 0
#count the number of char until the desired line
for i in range(1,exp):
    line = fo.readline()
    lngth = len(line) + lngth
# read the rest of the file
lines = fo.read()
# go back to insert position
fo.seek(lngth, 0)
# insert sequence in file
fo.writelines(seq)
# write rest of the file
fo.write(lines)
# Close opend file
fo.close()
```

For the original test input of :

```
This is 1st line
This is 2nd line
This is 3rd line
This is 4th line
This is 5th line
This is 6st line
This is 7nd line
This is 8rd line
This is 9th line
This is 10th line
```

I have got the following:

```
This is 1st line
This is 2nd line
This is 3rd line
This is 4th line
This is new line
This is new line
This is 5th line
This is 6st line
This is 7nd line
This is 8rd line
This is 9th line
This is 10th line
```

If you have a huge file what you cannot afford to load into RAM (see fo.read) you may want to use some other solutions with enumerate and line by line processing.
Hope this helps!